# Using Indy with Tor

Tags: delphi, http, indy, tor

I am building an application in witch privacy is essential. I need to send a HTTP Post request to a server .

How can I route the request trough Tor  ( https://www.torproject.org/ ) ?

Comment: have you asked Tor's community how to use their product? here they have a description of TOR's architecture - https://www.torproject.org/docs/documentation.html.en#DesignDoc

Comment: Wouldn't HTTPS be more suitable, perhaps fundamentally so?

Comment: @ChrisThornton I believe he is trying to use some form of more advanced proxy which "forgets" you've ever ran requests through it, I haven't used tor, but I think OP is over-engineering...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the FAQ - https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#CompatibleApplications

> There are two pieces to "Torifying" a program: connection-level
>   anonymity and application-level anonymity.
>
> Connection-level anonymity focuses on making sure the application's
>   Internet connections get sent through Tor. This step is normally done
>   by configuring the program to use your Tor client as a "socks" proxy,
>   (...)

Information on "How do I use a TIdTCPClient with a SOCKS Proxy?" can be found at

http://www.indyproject.org/KB/index.html?howdoiuseaproxywithindy.htm

(iirc IdHTTP is based on TIdTCPClient)